# Multiset notation in LaTeX

Tags: latex

Does anyone know how to make (nice looking) double bracket multiset notation in LaTeX, i.e something like `(\binom{n}{k})` where there are two outer brackets instead of 1 as in binomial? You can see an example of what I mean in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset under the heading "Multiset coefficients" with the double brackets.

In Wikipedia they typeset it as:

```
\left(\!\!{n\choose k}\!\!\right)
```

but although this works well for LaTeX in maths mode, with inline equations the outer bracket becomes much larger than the inner bracket.

I have also tried using

```
\genfrac{((}{))}{0pt}{}{n}{k}
```

but it has an error with the double brackets.

I am using `\binom` as well in my document, so I would like the bracket sizes to be similar for `\binom` and `\multiset`.

Comment: You might consider asking your question on http://tex.stackexchange.com/ which is like StackOverflow but focused on TeX and LaTeX.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly specify the size of the brackets via

```
\big( \Big( \bigg( or \Bigg(
```

Then use `\!` for negative space to get the brackets closer to each other.

Comment: But then I have to rewrite the spacing each time I want to use the notation, which is kind of what I used LaTeX to avoid.

Comment: Then make a new command using `\newcommand{\multsetl}{\Big(\!\big(}}` and accordingly for the right bracket.

Answer (score 3):

One can use the e-TeX `\middle` command as follows:

```
\newcommand{\multibinom}[2]{
  \left(\!\middle(\genfrac{}{}{0pt}{}{#1}{#2}\middle)\!\right)
}
```

This assumes that you are using the AMSmath package. If not, replace `\genfrac` with the appropriate construct using `\atop`.

(Of course this is a hack: the proper solution would be scalable glyphs for the doubled parenthesis, but I can't find any fonts that provide it.)

I'm surprised it wasn't googlable either, so I'll provide a solution here for posterity's sake.

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to define two different new commands, using `\tbinom` and `\dbinom` (section 4.11.2 of the [User's Guide for the `amsmath` Package](http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf)):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\inlinebnm}[2]{\ensuremath{\big(\!\tbinom{#1}{#2}\!\big)}}
\newcommand{\displybnm}[2]{\bigg(\!\!\dbinom{#1}{#2}\!\!\bigg)}

\begin{document}

Text $\inlinebnm{a}{b}$ text. %% inline

Text \inlinebnm{a}{b} text. %% inline (also ok thanks to ensuremath)

\[
\displybnm{a}{b} %% display-style
\]

\end{document}
```